# Google Cloud Java project cannot find endpoint library

Tags: java

I am trying to connect an app-engine application to a Tensforflow model running on a Vertex AI endpoint.
It works if I provide my personal authentication details but these need to be refreshed all the time.

Going through the documentation it sounds like App Engine can authenticate to an endpoint automatically using the endpoint APIs - Based on this [example](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-create-endpoint-sample)

Unfortunately Eclipse cannot find "com.google.cloud.aiplatform.*" and I am not sure which library should include this.

The documentation provides a list of all the standard libraries which can be defined in the [Eclispe built-path](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/libraries) but I am under the impression the endpoint API is not part of it.

Would be great to understand if there is a standard library I could add to make this work like "Google Cloud Platform Libraries -> Cloud Datastore"

Alternatively I could use another authentication method like an API keys but I could not figure out which service account needs which API key to authenticate against my end point.

Thank you

I am trying to compile the [sample example](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-create-endpoint-sample) provided here with Java 8 but Eclipse cannot find the library.

I was expecting to activate a standard Google Cloud library to get the example running and then figure out the authentication against the Google Cloud Endpoint.